# Laravel : Fetch big Data from Api (URL)

Tags: laravel, api, bigdata

Hwllo please i'm trying to fetch 15000 objects from api i used guzzle and file_get_contents but it's take long time and sometime the page doesn't load completely .
the controller :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $request = $client->get('http://XXX');
        $response = $request->getBody();
        $books = json_decode($response, true);

        return view('n.search', compact('books'));
```

the books variable return 10000 items and take very time to load !
Could you help me to fix that ?

Comment: It might be you reached already the time limit for execution that's why the content is no longer loaded. I suggest you use pagination for it. Pagination is very important to improve the performance of your request. It's not recommended to fetch all your data in just one request unless if your data is hundred only or lower.

Comment: if you have example please share them with me !  i tried to use DataTable but it's crushing since the page doesn't load completely , the tags doesn't close

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example just to give you an idea how I made this kind of problem.

in your controller, you should always paginate the returned collection of it. Like below

```
$users = User::all()->paginate(100);
```

laravel will return these 20 users together with some data like, next url, prev url, current_page and etc. These additional is important so that you will know what is the next url and prev url (these urls will be use in your api requests);

Now, after you get the paginated users, you need also to count the total users and return it together with users so that your front will know if how many pages it will display. Like this below

```
$total_users = User::all()->count();
```

now your final controller will look like this.

```
public function getUsers() {
    $users = User::all()->paginate(20);
    $total_users = User::all()->count();

    return compact('users', 'total_users');
}
```

and it will return these results.

```
users    // the 20 users
total_users // the total number of users in your table
currentPage
lastPage
perPage
hasMorePages
url
nextPageUrl
firstItem
lastItem
total
count
```

and so, every time you click pages in your datatable, you just need to use the next nextPageUrl and prevPageUrl as url in your api request.

Comment: i got it , Thanks

Comment: $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $request = $client->get('http://XXX');
        $response = $request->getBody();
        $books = json_decode($response, true);

        return view('n.search', compact('books'));
the books variable return 10000 items and take very time to load

Comment: please upvote my answer if it gives you an idea on how you will handle pagination in datatable

Comment: yes it does but only if i have a model as source for data (database) in my case i have URL JSON as source of data !

Comment: what do you mean of URL JSON as source of data ?

Comment: get data from api a link not from a database